# Enforcing a 1:1 Match Across Multiple Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very large data set in the following general form:

| Customer Name | Customer ID |
| --- | --- |
| Supplier 1 | 123345 |
| Supplier 2 | 987654 |

I have 96,000 or so of these types of records. What I'm trying to accomplish is to make sure that each unique Customer Name is attached to only one unique Customer ID, and vice versa. I can have duplicates of a Name-ID pair, but there's a lot of single unique Names that are attached to multiple different IDs and vice versa.

What's the easiest way to single out the Names associated with multiple IDs and the IDs associated with multiple Names? If I can find these, I can simply delete them from the sheet.

Comment: check and see if this works, assuming your data is in `A:B`... `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$96999,A2)=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$96999,B2)` and `FALSE` results should be mismatched pairs. rinse and repeat

Comment: Sort the column using [ Data > Filter > Sort ], if the name is repeated means there is 2 ID attached to it.

Comment: Try this formula: *=SUMPRODUCT((A1=$A$1:$A$8000)+(B1=$B$1:$B$8000 ))*  if the result is lager than 2, you should check the problem cells.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(CONCATENATE(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10;A2)>1;"Name not unique";"Unique Name");" / ";IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10;B2)>1;"ID not unique";"Unique ID"))="Unique Name / Unique ID";"Both, Name and ID are unique";CONCATENATE(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10;A2)>1;"Name not unique";"Unique Name");" / ";IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10;B2)>1;"ID not unique";"Unique ID")))

[Viaual result of above demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTaq8.png)

Code might to be changed dependent on local language, replace ";" with ","

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data is in columns A and B with the column headers you give in your example and the data starting in row 2. In that case, the following will show which lines are duplicates:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A3&"|"&B3,INDEX($A$2:A2&"|"&$B$2:B2,,1),1,FALSE)=A3&"|"&B3,"Duplicate",),"")
```

Make a "helper column" (as clearly you are willing to do) and enter this formula in the first data row's cell, then copy and paste down to the end of your data.

(Tiny point:  I did not fill in a value for the `IF()` to return for cases in which the `VLOOKUP()` would fail and the `IF()` is therefore FALSE because that will NEVER, EVER happen. So it wasn't needed. But if it feels less confusing, by all means add something like "Not a duplicate" for its FALSE result.)

The search value for `VLOOKUP()` is a combining of the two cells of data in each row. They are separated by the "|" character because sometimes unexpected pairing could match otherwise. Consider the simple Customer Name/ID pairs of `Cust 11 and 234` and `Cust 1 and 1234`:  without an unusual separator, you'd get a pairing of `CUST 11234` for both. With the separator, they are distinct. The "unusual separator" is so it is very unlikely to occur in the actual data.

It then uses `INDEX()` to collect all the rows of data ABOVE the current row and by joining them like done, they are formed just like the lookup value is formed. The two commas in a row after the joining that makes `INDEX()` make a data set for `VLOOKUP()` to search in are so that it returns all rows to `VLOOKUP()`. No value between them tells Excel to use all the rows, not one or some. Since the table combines the values in each row, you end up with a range that is many rows, but one column wide, so you must use "1" for `VLOOKUP()`'s return column.

ANY match it finds is a duplicate. That is because of the referencing used in the range for `INDEX()`. Notice that the first part is absolute and the second part is relative. So the range will be the first row down to the row just above the row the formula is in. The range for `INDEX()` keeps getting longer. This is one way to make a range "dynamic" which is a useful tool to have.

So, any match it finds is compared to the value that was looked up and obviously, it has to be equal to it so the `IF()` returns TRUE and places "Duplicate" in the cell.

Any and all failures to match will return an error. The `IFERROR()` takes over then and returns a blank cell. So you can scan down the column (if you realllly want to) and see something obvious when there's a duplicate and just blanks when they are acceptable pairs.

However, that is the very hard way to remove them. Instead, after copying the formula down, highlight the all the formula cells and copy them to the clipboard, then `Paste|Special|Values` to change them to just text. Sort the three columns by this one and all the lines saying "Duplicate" will sort into one big group. Highlight those rows and delete them. Problem gone. Delete the helper column and you have a clean data set.

There are other ways to show which are which, but since you are willing to just delete them and be done, this is the easiest way.

Any time you want to find out if more duplicates have come to exist, you can use the following formula. If it shows anything but 0, that many duplicates exist:

```
=ROWS(A2:A96001)-COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A96001&"|"&B2:B96001))
```

The `ROWS()` counts the number of rows in your table. Of course, if you have it literally specified like I do above, you COULD just put "96000" there instead. But you may be using a Named Range, determining the range dynamically, or using an actual Excel `Table` and then using the function would be required.

The `UNIQUE()` returns a list of all unique pairings and feeds it into the `COUNTA()` function which counts them up. The highest it can be (with the addresses above) is 96000 so then you'd have 96000-96000=0 duplicates. If there were a thousand duplicates, it would be 95000 so the subtraction would tell you 1,000.

Doing that could let you know immediately when a duplicate occurred. So it could be fixed immediately. And the problem might not arise again. If adding big batches of entries with copy and paste, or some other data loading, it would let you know if a problem just got created and how big of a problem it is. Useful stuff to know.